# How to join domain name to a list of short hostname

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have list of short hostnames and string of domain name

How can I join these together?

```yaml
dns_domain: 'local.out'
short_nodes: [ name1, name2, name3 ]
```

and I want

```
[ name1.local.out, name2.local.out, name3.local.out ]
```

I tried

```yaml
set_facts:
  nodes: "{{ short_nodes | default([]) + ['.'.join( {{ dns_domain }}) }}
```

but, that gives me error.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a [`product`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#products) to map your domain name to each nodes.
Then, it is easy to [`join`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.join) the lists of list created with [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map).

Given the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: short_nodes  | product([dns_domain])  |  map('join', '.')
  vars:
    dns_domain: local.out
    short_nodes:
      - name1
      - name2
      - name3
```

This yields

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  short_nodes  | product([dns_domain])  |  map('join', '.'):
  - name1.local.out
  - name2.local.out
  - name3.local.out
```

Comment: Thanks for reply

I saw documentation for products and looked promising.

so I tried


my_list: "{{ short_nodes | product([dns_domain]) | map('join', '.') }}" 

produces

<generator object do_map at 0x7f3xxxxx>

if add | list then each character from short_nodes gets appended with dns_domain value.

What I am missing?

Comment: umm if I do  "{{ short_nodes | from_yaml | list | product([dns_domain]) | map('join', '.') }}"  that kind of works but it shows those u' character in the output ...uhmm

Comment: Drop a `| list` as a last filter. You are on an old version of Ansible that do not automatically cast generators back to list when the  current versions does it by itself

Comment: adding '| list' at the end didn't work either.. i get yml as - u'name1'.<domain_name> :-(

Comment: uhmm i think it has to do with the original list was set with <raw> <endraw> tags.. I am new to elastic but once i stopped using it it is working! thanks for your help.